# calling new thread inside is constructor

Tags: java, multithreading

Is it correct to create a thread and call its start() method inside a class' constructor as done here?

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

    private ServerSocket server;

    public Server(int port) {
        try {
            //Opens a new server 
            server = new ServerSocket(port);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        new Thread(this, "Server").start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IMHO, do not do this. You're allowing the `this` reference to escape during construction.

Comment: @Mazzy, You're allowing another object to view a partially constructed object, which can have severely negative side-effects.

Comment: You can use a static factory method to achieve the desired effect without the negative side effects.

Comment: @mre What could be the solution to avoid this problem?

Comment: @Mazzy, Declare a method that is to be invoked after the `Server` object has been constructs (e.g. `start()`).

Comment: @mre do you refer to the method start() belongs to class Thread ? Like this : Thread t = new Thread(s, "Server").start() ?

Comment: @Mazzy, No, as part of your `Server` class. Perhaps to disambiguate, declare the method as `startServer()`.

Comment: @mre well excuse me but I don'd understand the sense.I have to create in another class the object new Thread(new Server(port)).start() ?Can you write the code so I could understand?

Comment: @Mazzy, I put some static factory method code here http://stackoverflow.com/a/8855873/348975

Comment: @mre I don't think your start method idea will achieve the desired result.  Assuming initialization succeeds, it is impossible to create a Server that has not been started.  As I understand your start method idea, I could create a Server and choose not to start it.

Comment: @emory, IMHO, a server should be explicitly started, and not upon construction.

Answer (score 2):

Granted, your code isnt doing it but what if your code looked like this:

```
public Server(int port)
{       
    new Thread(this, "Server").start();

    try
    {
        //Opens a new server 
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace(); }

}
@Override    
public void run(){
    if(server == null)throw new NullPointerException();// this may happen
}
}
```

The server reference may be null even though no exception occurs.  This is because the Thread will use the created runnable and invoke the run method even if the constructor of your class hasn't finished.

Answer (score 1):

```
Server s = new Server();
Thread t = new Thread(s, "Server").start();
```

is more testable. It allows you to create an instance of Server and unit test its methods without spawning a thread.

Answer (score 1):

A couple more good reasons to split the Thread.start() from the constructor:

1. If you ever want to use some other framework/system to run the threads, such as a java.util.concurrent.Executor, you may do so.
2. If you ever want to interrupt the thread, you need a reference to it.  Creating the Thread in a separate line of code makes this somewhat more routine / idiomatic.  e.g.

   Thread rememberMe = new Thread(server).start();

In your original code, Server could have a field to remember myThread, but it didn't.

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Server implements Runnable
{
private ServerSocket server;

/**
 * Because the constructor is private, the only way to instantiate a Server is through
 * the static factory method.
 * If there are any instantiation problems, the static factory method will fail in
 * first line, before it is put into a thread.
 * It will be put into a thread before being released.
 **/    
public static Server startServer ( int port )
{
    Server server = new Server ( port ) ;
    new Thread ( server , "Server" ) . start ( ) ;
    return server ;
}

private Server(int port)
{       
    try
    {
        //Opens a new server 
        server = new ServerSocket(port);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe){ ioe.printStackTrace(); }

//    don't release me into the wild yet!
//    new Thread(this, "Server").start();
}
@Override    
public void run(){
}
}
```

Comment: What's the meaning to add the value return Server ?

Comment: It is necessary if you want a reference to the created server.  If you just want to create and start a server, it is not needed.

Comment: @emory, +1 This is similar to the `newInstance` approach.